# How to fetch the integer from firestore flutter? _TypeError(type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int)

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, number-formatting

user_repo.dart

```
Future<List<UserModel>> fetchUsers() async {

    var usercollection = await users.get();
    var userList = usercollection.docs.map((e) => EU.fromSnapShot(e)).toList();
    print("repo: ${userList[1].avgRating}");
    return userList;
    
  }
}
```

user_model.dart

```
class UserModel{
  final String user_id;
  final String username;
  String currentProfile = '--';
  double yearsOfExp = 0;
  String smallIntro = "";
  String emailId = "";
  String image;
  int avgRating;
  EU({
    this.user_id,
    this.username,
    this.currentProfile,
    this.smallIntro,
    this.yearsOfExp,
    this.emailId,
    this.image,
  this.avgRating}) ;

  UserModel.fromSnapShot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : assert(snapshot != null),
        eu_id =
            snapshot.data()['userId'] != null ? snapshot.data()['userId'] : 'null',
        username = snapshot.data()['username'],
        image = snapshot.data()['profile_img_url'],
        emailId = snapshot.data()['email'],
        avgRating =  snapshot.data()['avg_rating'];      
}
```

Getting this error while fetching avgRating which is stored as a number on Cloud Firestore. I have tried

1. avgRating =  int.parse(snapshot.data()['avg_rating'].toString());  same error
2. avgRating =  snapshot.data()['avg_rating'] as int; typecast error
3. avgRating =  snapshot.data()['avg_rating'].toDouble();  No such method found
4. avgRating =  snapshot.data()['avg_rating'] as num; typecast error

I would really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: What is `snapshot.data()['avg_rating']` type? int or String?

Comment: Did you try int.parse(snapshot.data()[‘avg_rating’]); without toString ?

Comment: Yes, I tried that without .toString It didn't help.

Comment: Its number retrieved from the firestore.

Answer (score 0):

So I tried changing the data type while declaring the value to 'var avgRating' and it worked. If I declare it with int or double it gives the same error. I think because firestore's number type supports multiple data types like int, double.

Thanks for the help!